# Equation $\displaystyle\lim_{ x \rightarrow \infty } \left( \dfrac{ \sqrt{ 16x ^ { 2 } +1 \phantom{\tiny{!}}} }{ 3x-5 } \right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you solve
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\! \frac{\sqrt{16x^2 + 1\,}}{3x - 5}   \right)?
$$
We think the answer is $\frac43$, but how can the numerator can be $4$?

Comment: Divide the numerator and denominator by $x$.

$$\frac {\sqrt{16x^2+1}}{3x-5}=\frac {\sqrt{16+\frac 1{x^2}}}{3-\frac 5x}$$

Now, as $x\to\infty$, what happens to $\frac 5x$? What about $\frac 1{x^2}$?

Answer (score 2):

As long as $x \neq 0$, we can multiply the numerator and denominator by $\frac1x$. This is a reasonable assumption since we're considering large positive values of $x$ as $x \to \infty$ Moreover, since $x > 0$,
$$
\frac1x = \sqrt{\frac{1\strut}{x^2}}.
$$
Thus,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} 
\frac{\sqrt{16x^2 + 1\,}}{3x - 5}
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} 
\frac{\frac1x\sqrt{16x^2 + 1\,}}{\frac1x(3x - 5)} \\[2pt]
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} 
\frac{\sqrt{16 + \frac{1}{x^2}\,}}{3 - \frac5x} \\[2pt]
&= \frac{\sqrt{16 + 0\,}}{3 - 0} \\[2pt]
&= \frac43
\end{align}